# Size of prefab when spawning in panel is too small

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm spawning prefab in a panel but it's size is too small like a dot but when I spawn it outside the panel there's no problem . Please check below image and code

[image]

```
public class RedKeyShapeSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject redshapes;

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject redkeychild1 = Instantiate(redshapes, transform.position, 
transform.rotation) as GameObject; 
        redkeychild1.transform.SetParent(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag
("ShapePanel").transform, false);

    }


    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

RedKeyShapeSpawn script is attached to RedKey1spawn object

Comment: did you try to directly spawn it as child of the panel? `GameObject redkeychild1 = Instantiate(redshapes, transform.position, 
transform.rotation, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag
("ShapePanel").transform);` otherwise try to make the last parameter `true` in `SetParent`

Comment: @derHugo tried your code but still the same, if I set the parameter to true the prefab goes out of screen.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that when you spawn you object inside the panel it will inherit the parent position and use that as a reference (x,y and z are relative).
You should be able to solve this problem if, for example, your panel in in the origin (0,0,0) or if you set an absolute position in your code.

PS. Same thing with rotation and scale

Answer (score 1):

The culprit of this issue is likely the transform of the `ShapePanel`. If the transform of that object is not 1x1x1 then any objects added as a child of the panel will be affected by it.

Consider making the prefab a child of the panel, and rescale it accordingly. Then when you spawn the prefab and add it as a child of the panel, the scale of the `RedKey` should be as you expect.

Comment: didn't work . I tried adding this redkeychild1.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1,1,1); but still doesn't work

Comment: @Newboy11 You might need to delete your prefab and remake it. Delete the current prefab, add a new `RedKey` as a child of your `ShapePanel` in the inspector, size it accordingly, then make it a prefab while it's still a child. After that you should be able to delete it from the inspector. When you spawn the prefab spawn it with the `ShapePanel` as the parent